# making parallel ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

i have javascript code that does these things in a loop

1. create a `div` element,append it to the `dom` and get its reference
2. pass this reference to a function that makes an ajax `post` request
3. set the response of the ajax request to the `innerHTML` of the passed element reference

here is the code

```
window.onload = function () {
    var categories = document.getElementById('categories').children;
    for (i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        var link = categories[i].children[1].children[0].attributes['href'].nodeValue;
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = "books";
        div.style.display = "none";
        categories[i].appendChild(div);
        getLinks(link, div);
    }
}

function getLinks(url, div) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'ebook_catg.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    url = encodeURIComponent(url)
    var post = "url=" + url;
    xhr.node=div;                         //in response to Marc B's suggestion
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            xhr.node.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            xhr.node.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    xhr.send(post);
}
```

now when i check this in `firebug` i can see that the `div` element is created and appended to the `categories` element and its display is set to `hidden`. also the `ajax post` requests are being sent and the response is being received as expected. But the `innerHTML` property of `div` is not set and neither its display is set to `block`.
This means that the function `getLinks` loses the `div` reference.

**when i type `console.log(div)` in the firefox console it says `ReferenceError: div is not defined`.**

can somebody explain whats going on here?

---

in response to Franks's comment i changed `readystate` to `readyState` and i am able to attach the response of the last ajax request to the dom. so that makes it obvious that the `div` reference is being lost.

Comment: `readystate` should be `readyState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you've got a few globals going on that you don't want. Rule of thumb: unless you need to access a variable outside of a function, place `var` in front of it. Otherwise you'll have data clobbering itself all over the place:

```
// changed the name to `d` because div seems to already be a global var.
function getLinks(url, d) {
    // make xhr a local variable so it won't get re-written.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'ebook_catg.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    url = encodeURIComponent(url)
    var post = "url=" + url;
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // when the request was global, this would be false until the last 
        // request completed
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            // since d only exists as a parameter to getLinks, this should 
            // already be bound when the onreadystatechange is created.
            d.innerHTML = request.responseText;
            d.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    request.send(post);
}
```

So, why did I just do such strange, strange things? Well, it looks like div was being assigned as a global variable and while JS *should* always look to function parameter name for binding, we want to eliminate all possible problems. So I changed the name of that variable. Then I set xhr to reflect a local variable with the var keyword. I also changed the name to request. Once again, it shouldn't matter -- var means that the variable will be bound to that scope, but the change is harmless and since I don't know what else you have, I decided to remove ambiguities. If it does not help JS, it will at least help the reader.

### NOTE:

The important part of the above answer is var in front of request.

Comment: `div` is not a global variable. it has a `var`.

Comment: Didn't know if it was or wasn't, but you definitely need the var in front of your XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked. I was thinking on the right track but was being silly at the `XMLHttpRequest` place. i edited my answer. can u please tell me if my thoughts were correct(mentioned in italics)?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you are using a public (global) variable `div` that keeps getting overwritten.

Try this in your `for loop`:

```
for (i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    var link = categories[i].children[1].children[0].attributes['href'].nodeValue;
    var div = document.createElement('div'); //USE var!
    div.className = "books";
    div.style.display = "none";
    categories[i].appendChild(div);
    getLinks(link, div);
}
```

Comment: that doesnt help Neal. i used `var div` and made it local but the same result as before

Comment: @lovesh -- you sure you are ever reaching `if (xhr.readystate == 4)` ?? try using the `console.log` to log `xhr` after that point

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the response handlers innards aren't "fixated" when the callback is defined, so the 'current' value of the div var doesn't get embedded into the function's definition. It'll only be resolved when the function actually executes, by which time it might have been set to some completely other div, or been reset to null as the parent function's scope has been destroyed.

You could store the div value as a data attribute on the xhr object, which you can then retrieve from within the callback:

```
xhr.data('thediv', div);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readystate == 4) {
            div = xhr.data('thediv');
     etc....
```

Comment: can u be more clear when u say `esponse handlers innards aren't "fixated"`

Comment: Think of the div var as a note to the system telling it to look up div's value at the time the onreadystatechange executes, instead of embedding whatever div's value is at the time that function is defined

Comment: does the XMLHttpRquest object has a data attribute?

Comment: It would if you were using jquery, otherwise you could just assign something to the object directly (`xhr.thediv = div`).

Comment: i tried this like `xhr.data=div` and then inside `onreadystatechange` i tried `xhr.data.innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
xhr.data.style.display="block";` but only the last `div` is being appended to the `dom`

Answer (score 0):

here i am answering my question.The following code works,i mean the response from each post is appended to the corresponding `div` element.

```
var xhr=new Array();

window.onload=function() {
var categories=document.getElementById('categories').children;
for(i=0;i<categories.length;i++)
{
var link=categories[i].children[1].children[0].attributes['href'].nodeValue;
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.className="books";
div.style.display="none";
categories[i].appendChild(div);
getLinks(link,div,i);
}
}

function getLinks(url,div,i)
{
xhr[i]=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr[i].open('POST','ebook_catg.php',true);
xhr[i].setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
url=encodeURIComponent(url)
var post="url="+url;
xhr[i].node=div;
xhr[i].onreadystatechange=function() {
if(xhr[i].readyState==4)
{
xhr[i].node.innerHTML=xhr[i].responseText;
xhr[i].node.style.display="block";
}
}
xhr[i].send(post);
}
```

*i am not marking it as accepted because i still dont understand why i need to use an array of `xhr` since a local `xhr` object should be enough because each time the `onreadystate` function executes it has the reference of the `xhr` object. Now since javascript functions are also objects therefore every instance of `onreadystate` function should have its own reference of `xhr` object and therefore i shouldnt need to create an array of `xhr`s*. 
**please correct me if i am wrong here**